# What is the correct way to update a record based on the profile that created it?

Tags: workflow, process

What is the correct way to update a record based on the profile that created it?

For example if the user belongs to profile X then I want all Contacts they create to be assigned to Account Z.  I want to accomplish this automatically and currently my thinking is a Process designed via the Process Builder.  Is this correct or would a trigger or workflow be more suitable.

Note I have currently tried creating a Process as:

- On Contact
- If created by Profile with ID: XXX = True
- Immediate Action to update Contact record (All) setting the field Account ID with type ID to the value of XXX (account record id)

I logged in via the user and this didn't work :(

Comment: Please make sure that you activate the process builder manually once created.

Comment: yeah sorry I should have confirmed I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can automate this functionality using Process Builder however it doesn't work sometimes when record size is huge.

I would recommend you Process Builder only if you insert Contacts not very frequently and records are less at a time.

You can write trigger also for bulk records:-

```
trigger sample on Contact (Before Insert){

 for ( Contact c: trigger.new ){

   if ( UserInfo.getProfileId() == 'XYZ' )
   c.AccountId = 'Z';
}
}
```

Comment: So if we consider at most we would get maybe 50 contacts an hour from all of our staff.  Would you say that's too many for the Process Builder?

Comment: There is no issue with number of Contacts created at different time. Only issue might occur when 50 contacts are inserted at once like using DataLoader etc.

Comment: Ah, apologies I understand now.  Chances are the profile in question won't ever be doing that so I think we are safe.  I appreciate it.  You've answered my questions so I've marked it as answered.